# John Lee, CW construction, p139, components of nth skeleton

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, cw-complexes

This is from John M Lee's Topological manifold and the CW construction theorem (p139).

> **Theorem:** Suppose $X_0 \subseteq X_1 \subseteq \cdots $ is a sequence of topological space satisfying the following conditions
>
> (i) $X_0$ is a nonempty discrete space.
>
> (ii)For each $n \ge 1$, $X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching a (possibly empty) collection of $n$ cells.
>
> Then $X= \bigcup_n X_n$ has a unique topology coherent with the family $\{X_n\}$ and a unique cell decomposition making it into a CW complex whose $n$-skeleton is $X_n$ for each $n$.
>
> **Proof:** Give $X$ the final topology given by inclusion maps $i_n:X_n \rightarrow X$ ... *The $n$-cells of any such decompositions are the components of $X_n \setminus X_{n-1}$*...

I do not understand why the itacilized line is true. Each $n$ cell must be connected but why are they precisely the components? We do not even know what open sets partition them.

> **Note**: The definition the book take for CW complex is that the space X has cell decomposition which satisfies closure finities and weakest topology with respect to the collection of closed cells.
>
> **Definition:** A closed (open) $n$ cell is a topological space homeomorphic to $\bar{\mathbb{B}}^n$( $\mathbb{B}^n$).
>   If $X$ is a nonempty topological space, a cell decomposition of $X$ is a partition $\mathcal{E}$ of $X$ into subspaces that are open cells of various dimneions such that : for each cell $e \in \mathcal{E}$ of dimension $n \ge 1$, exists a continuous map $\Phi$ from closed $n$-cell $D$ into $X$, the characteristic map for $e$ that restriction a homeomoprhism from $Int \, D $ into $e$ and maps $\partial D$ into the union of all cells of $\mathcal{E}$ of dimension strict less than $n$.

Comment: By assumption $X_n\cong X_{n-1}\bigcup_\varphi\left(\bigsqcup_\alpha D_\alpha\right)$. It follows that there is a homeomorphism $X_n\mbox{-}X_{n-1}\cong \bigsqcup_\alpha  \mathring{D^n}$ with adisjoint union of open n-disks, indexed over the n-cells of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Every open $n$-cell $U$ is an open subset of $X_n$.  To prove this, we use the fact that $X_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching $n$-cells, so a subset of $X_n$ is open iff its intersection with $X_{n-1}$ is open in $X_{n-1}$ and its inverse image under the characteristic map of each $n$-cell is open.  In this case, $U\cap X_{n-1}$ is empty, as is the inverse image of $U$ under the characteristic map of any $n$-cell other than $U$ itself.  The inverse image of $U$ under its own characteristic map $D\to X_n$ is the interior of $D$, which is open in $D$.  Thus $U$ is open in $X_n$.

In particular, then, the open $n$-cells form a partition of $X_n\setminus X_{n-1}$ by open sets.  Since each one is connected, they are the connected components of $X_n\setminus X_{n-1}$.

Comment: Hi Eric. I think Lee wants to prove the uniqueness of such decomposition here, so instead of using THE decomposition you give (by attaching n-cells), we need to prove that n-cell is component of $X_n-X_{n-1}$ for the  decomposition given by any Characteristic map?

Comment: @ Eric Wofsey: Thanks for replying. Do you mean the cell decomposition of $X$ s.t. $X_n$ is the n-skeleton is not unique, but the CW decomposition s.t. $X_n$ is the n-skeleton is unique. And any CW complex is obtained from attaching n-cells by the preceding proposition, so your proof works?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was confused in my last reply.  To address your initial question, it makes no difference--the exact same argument works for any such CW decomposition, since any decomposition will have $X_n$ obtained from $X_{n-1}$ by attaching the $n$-cells.